# Opening a Webpage at an Anchor in a Browser through Java

Tags: java, html, swing, anchor

I have created an application in JSwing that has a button that I want to open the user manual (which is a html file) in a browser. I can successfully open the entire webpage, but I want to link to certain anchors in the document. For example I am trying to use this code:

```
    URI uri = new URI("c:/Giggafriggin/user_manual/user_manual.html#h1_3");
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
```

But this causes an error, claiming the file cannot be found. But if leave off "#h1_3" it opens the page in a browser without a problem. The anchors work when i enter them into the browser manually. Any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid `file:` URI to me..

Answer (score 0):

You -could- have that linking to another html page which goes to the end uri. Unfortunately, Java is not a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a [known issue](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6477862) you wouldn't run into if you were using HTTP instead of a local file.

One easy fix is simply to point to a version of the that's already online instead of on disk.

If you can't assume the content is available online, you could always spin up [an embedded HTTP server like jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html) inside your application and point to that instead.